# Allow only certain type for specific object key in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following categories of `Pet`:

type Pet = 'dog' | 'cat'

Then I have types for allowed `DogName`s and `CatName`s respectively:

type DogName = 'Jack' | 'Fenton'
type CatName = 'Priscilla' | 'Kittykat'

I want to type the following object so that only cat names are allowed under cat and dog names are only allowed under dog, but I also don't want new pet categories to be invented unless they are in the type:

```js
type Pet = 'dog' | 'cat'
type DogName = 'Jack' | 'Fenton'
type CatName = 'Priscilla' | 'Kittykat'

type Pets = {
   ["dog" in Pet]: {[key in DogName]: boolean}
   ["cat" in Pet]: {[key in CatName]: boolean}
}

const pets = {
   dog: {
      Jack: true
   },
   cat: {
      KittyKat: true
   }
}
```

The above does not work, specifically the part of  `"dog" in Pet`

Comment: Are both `dog` and `cat` meant to be required in `Pets`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, for the pet type, the same mapped structure you are using for the names, and get the associated names with a conditional type.

As suggested by [caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/cats), consider changing the conditional to a lookup table for performance and maintainability in the future when there are more members of the union.

```
type Pet = 'dog' | 'cat'
type DogName = 'Jack' | 'Fenton'
type CatName = 'Priscilla' | 'Kittykat'

type NameFromPetType<PetType extends Pet> = PetType extends 'dog' ? DogName : CatName;
type Pets = {
   [PetType in Pet]: {[key in NameFromPetType<PetType>]?: boolean}
}
```

<kbd>[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChxQLxQOQBMD2BzFUA+qAxgIbAoBQokUAItgHLEC20yKAUsYQNa4EoAxCADtgGYRSrQAwqUYskqGACcAlgGdCqgDbbifVAGlVwUN1IVK4aPIgDlGJnGAAVawB5nb6hAAewETR1WHgAPkUvayg-AOEg1EwcKAB+WgZmaAAuKFlgWwBuK2pnYOQAb3IoKoBtSOpVYRDgAF1ssuruCBAoBqhbe0c6iE94bwhQ5uTsgCMMDG0IYmEAX3JV8gB6ACod3b39vY3yckJxdQRIYHUARmySxQqqqES2yqeqzh5s4GUAVwgADRvKDLIFPEjAV7vKrGUwgcyQqA-f5gqqgtbHU7Cc5QS7qABMd3gpSgjyqL1JwKen243z+gOB6PBpCh0NhZhZSPpqPeNLpKMZQPWWJxeIAzESrg9gRSybyuLSuQKnkyqhDWe92fDOciGSqeQAzDQACw1TwAQr9ptMFvy9WihUA)</kbd>

Comment: Consider changing the conditional to a lookup table for performance and maintainability in the future when there are more members of the union.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is tell TypeScript that `pets` should be of type `Pets`. :-)

Then the pedestrian way to do this is to use `Partial<Record<___, boolean>>`:

```typescript
type Pets = {
    dog: Partial<Record<DogName, boolean>>;
    cat: Partial<Record<CatName, boolean>>;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChxQLxQEQBMD2BzFUA+qAxgIbAoDcAUKJFACLYByxAttMigFLGEDWuBFADEIAO2AZRFauGgBhUszZJUMAE4BLAM6ENAGz3EBqANIbgoE6WkzacYFpUBvSlDdRMWAFyxia4BrEegA8AEoQhBhqaMEMWEoQADRQAEYYGHoQxKIAfDlU7lAkwD4wfgFBYRFRMQrACclpGVm5+ZQAvlSUAPTdUADqUbxalJGiWgiQDqXwjsguhZ4+C4Xu3Hw+wGoArkmu7u2J+27Fy8erZhYgViVQW7tHhYcdXb30GBBaogDkCADuQy8o0kEygUy0ACYZg5nOcllAVqsoJdLKRNjsklA3sFEMgAKJqNRRKDERxoT4aNQQNA+FAAFVkUG+TmR5lAvDRdwx5Cg7W+UG0UFEGAQpK0GiwomIKUydwwd0Z3zK-kCIXCkWisSYrExTUy2Ty3wAdChzs9CqcEedCijrpz7nsnkdOkA) *(I made the capitalization of `KittyKat` consistent)*

Obviously, you'll need to add to `Pets` if you add to `Pet`, but that'll be the case in any solution.